# Подключение двух проектов к одной БД mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb

К одному проекту подключена mongodb. Есть второй проект к которому нужно подключить эту же БД. Когда подключаю и запускаю проект, то не грузит БД в первом проекте, а второй не запускается вообще.
Подключаюсь точно так же как и в первом проекте. Порт, название и тд, всё идентично.

**Вот собственно вопрос, как подключиться к одной БД с двух проектов ?**

Comment: Подключение всегда одинаково делается. Если не работает, что-то у вас в коде не так. Что у вас не так без кода мы не догадаемся. Что за ошибки получаете? Что значит "не грузит БД", "не запускается"? Это нужно добавить в вопрос.

Comment: Замечу, что подключать два разных проекта к одной БД обычно плохая идея

Comment: Возникла такая ситуация, никак не могу это изменить. Сказали нужно подключить второй проект, значит надо подключить.

Comment: @VladimirBabaev всё же для того чтобы Вам ответить формулировки "не запускается вообще" не достаточно. Нужна более детальная техническая информация.

Comment: попробуйте добавить SITE_ID